# Elasticsearch Aggregations: Volume-Weighted Average Price

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I need to plot the [Volume-Weighted Average Prive (VWAP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume-weighted_average_price) of trades having a `price_per_unit` and a `quantitiy` over a certain time range.

As a result of the aggregation every bucket of the `date_histogram` should contain the VWAP of the all trades that happened so far.

I'm not really sure if this is possible using Elasticsearch and also not what would be the right way to approach it (like using a script?)?

The basic mapping for a `trade` document is quite simple:

```
"trade": {
  "properties": 
    "trade_id": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
    "product_id": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
    "quantity": {'type': 'double'}, // number of units
    "execution_time": {'type': 'date'},
    "price_per_unit": {'type': 'double'},
  }
}
```

Whereas `execution_time` should be used for the `date_histogram` and the total price of the trade is the product of`price_per_unit` and `quantity`. Therefore the `VWAP = sum(price_per_unit * quantity) / sum(quantity)`.

Comment: Sounds like a [cumulative sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html) would help.

Comment: Could you come up with a code sample for the question from above? I tried looking into cumulative sum but couldnt really implement it.

Comment: There is a sample in the link I provided. And I am not able to come up with a better sample than that one since you haven't provided any test data, desired output and mappings of the index.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I've updated the question with the relevant mapping, `price_per_unit` and `quantity` are just numbers, so no real sample data needed; thanks for you help, it's appreciated a lot as it is difficult to wrap your head around ES' aggregations in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "trade": {
      "properties": {
        "trade_id": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "product_id": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "execution_time": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "price_per_unit": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/trade/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"execution_time":"2016-11-18T22:45:27Z","quantity":10,"price_per_unit":5}
{"index":{}}
{"execution_time":"2016-11-18T22:45:27Z","quantity":10,"price_per_unit":5}
{"index":{}}
{"execution_time":"2016-11-19T22:45:27Z","quantity":10,"price_per_unit":5}
{"index":{}}
{"execution_time":"2016-11-20T22:45:27Z","quantity":10,"price_per_unit":5}
{"index":{}}
{"execution_time":"2016-11-20T22:45:27Z","quantity":10,"price_per_unit":5}
{"index":{}}
{"execution_time":"2016-11-20T22:45:27Z","quantity":10,"price_per_unit":5}
{"index":{}}
{"execution_time":"2016-11-21T22:45:27Z","quantity":10,"price_per_unit":5}
{"index":{}}
{"execution_time":"2016-11-21T22:45:27Z","quantity":10,"price_per_unit":5}

POST test/trade/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sales_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "execution_time",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sales": {
          "sum": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "groovy",
              "inline": "doc['quantity'] * doc['price_per_unit']"
            }
          }
        },
        "cumulative_sales": {
          "cumulative_sum": {
            "buckets_path": "sales"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you need to enable [inline scripting for groovy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!